# Artifactory Maven layout version

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I would like to know what dictates when an artifact is deployed to snapshot vs release repo.

Artifactory has two repos:

1. `libs-snapshot`
2. `libs-release`

Layout for both:
`[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]`

When I run the Jenkins Pipeline the artifacts are always uploaded to `libs-release`. Note that I do not explicitly put a `SNAPSHOT` modifier in my pom files. Snapshots have version with build number (e.g. `1.0.0-010`) while release only has version (e.g. `1.0.0`)

`rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot', server: rtServer`

How does the Artifactory plugin decide if it should go to release vs snapshot repo here? Is it the fileItegRev? or folderItegRev?

Answer (score 1):

A snapshot is a version that ends with `-SNAPSHOT`. It has to be in the path of the artifact to deploy, as gathered by build info extractor.

Relevant [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin/blob/dcda06bef2cbe19848d7f7a7f368e59109388e87/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/common/types/deployers/MavenDeployer.java#L90) is:

```
public String getTargetRepository(String deployPath) {
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(snapshotRepo) && deployPath.contains("-SNAPSHOT") ? snapshotRepo : releaseRepo;
}
```